# Effect of antenna direction on antenna gain

Tags: antenna, gain

I'm studying antenna theory right now, and I have a question about the effect of antenna direction on antenna gain.

My assumption of the antenna direction is like below:

[image]

Since the Rx antenna cannot get the signal from the Tx antenna, I thought receive antenna gain would be zero.

As a result, based on the Friis equation, \$P_r\$ will be zero too.

$$\frac{P_r}{P_t} = G_tG_r\left(\frac{\lambda}{4\pi d}\right)^2$$

If the antenna's direction is parallel, is the gain of RX antenna zero because of its direction? Am I right?

Comment: If the antenna really had zero gain in that direction then yes it would receive nothing. Probably in the real world it would receive a very weak signal because the gain never goes all the way to zero.

Comment: @user1850479 So, you mean except main lobe, the Friis equation's G_r is very small because of its direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the antenna's direction is parallel, is the gain of RX antenna zero because of its direction? Am I right?

Yes you are right. Take for example the following definition for antenna gain taken from wikipedia

> The ratio of the radiation intensity in a given direction to the radiation intensity that would be produced if the power accepted by the antenna were isotropically radiated

Gain is the ratio of power received and powerr received by an hypothetical isotrpoic radiator **in a given direction**. It is a function of direction, when it is given as a single number it is in the direction of maximum gain.

In your hypothetical case, power received in the direction of the TX antenna is 0, so gain is 0 (as correctly noted in a comment in a real case won't probably be zero but some very small amount, we use dB to work with quantities with such dynamic range)

Answer (score 1):

> *If antenna's direction is parallel, is the gain of rx antenna zero
> because of its direction(Am I right)?*

The analogy of lamps and vision is fairly useful.

If you have a normal regular lamp, it "sprays" light pretty much in all directions roughly equally. This is nearly equivalent to an isotropic antenna.

If you collimated the lamp so that it focused its light in only one direction, then this would be equivalent to your "Tx" diagram. Only when your eyes moved to within the path of the focused light would you see anything.

On the other hand, if instead of collimating the lamp you collimated your eyes with say a carboard tube (as per your "RX" diagram), you would have to be pointing the tube at the lamp to see light.

If both lamp and eye were collimated then, to see light, both collimators would need to be on the same trajectory and angle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
So I understand your answer like "except main lobe, the Friis equation's G_r is very small because of its direction". 
Is it right?

Comment: @new_be an antenna's gain is not a simple number. It's a 3 dimensional quantity that has a magnitude in all directions from the mean dead centre of the antenna. However, in simple specifications, if the gain is quoted as being (say) 10 dBi then that will likely be the gain at its most efficient angle. But that doesn't mean it won't be 10 dBi at some other angles. In other words you have to consider the bigger picture when it comes to antennas. If you have the wrong direction, then gain will be very, very low on some directional antennas.

Answer (score 1):

The function which describes the gain of an antenna in different directions is called the [radiation pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pattern).

Radiation patterns are usually a lot more complex than “gain is X within this cone and 0 elsewhere”. First, it’s not constant within a given angle of the “direction “ of the antenna, but there’s also additional directions to/from which signals can be sent/received.

Even directional antennas often have a smaller “back lobe” and even smaller “side lobes”.

[image]

(Image source: Wikipedia)

Note that this is a 2D radiation pattern in the plane of the antenna axis, but radiation patterns are actually in 3D.

So even though in theory you wouldn’t receive anything, in practice you may receive a signal (it may be very weak, though).

Also in some circumstances you may have a reflections/multi path.